# node-sails app is getting stop in every 24 hours or earlier on server

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pm2

I have two sails js apps on two servers but my both apps on one server are getting stop in every 24 hours, I usually check both the app in the morning and it shows the following after running
 `pm2 list` or    `pm2 restart all`:-

```
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2][WARN] No process found
```

and every time I had to go to their directory and run the command:- `pm2 start app.js` individually, but both the apps on another server are working correctly.
Please suggest what should I do?
Thanks
Now my service is stoped and after running pm2 logs its showing:

```
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
########### Starting streaming logs for [all] process
Can not find log files, try to reload logs by executing "pm2 reload <name|all>".
PM2: 2015-07-17 03:27:22: App name:app id:0 online
PM2: child_process.js:935
PM2:     throw errnoException(process._errno, 'spawn');
PM2:           ^
PM2: Error: spawn ENOMEM
PM2:     at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
PM2:     at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:935:11)
PM2:     at exports.spawn (child_process.js:723:9)
PM2:     at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:607:15)
PM2:     at exports.exec (child_process.js:578:18)
PM2:     at Object.parseHg [as parse] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/vizion/lib/hg.js:36:2)
PM2:     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/vizion/lib/vizion.js:16:24
PM2:     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/vizion/lib/identify.js:18:12
PM2:     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:151:21
PM2:     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/vizion/lib/identify.js:12:16
PM2: 2015-07-20 06:23:46: [PM2][WORKER] Started with refreshing interval: 30000
PM2: 2015-07-20 06:23:46: [[[[ PM2/God daemon launched ]]]]
PM2: 2015-07-20 06:23:46: BUS system [READY] on port /root/.pm2/pub.sock
PM2: 2015-07-20 06:23:46: RPC interface [READY] on port /root/.pm2/rpc.sock
```

and after running pm2 list or pm2 restart all its showing:

```
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2][WARN] No process found
```

plz help I am totally stuck in this.

Thanks

Comment: could be a memory issue. How much ram is there ?

Comment: but both the servers have same configurations and now 468 MB is available on both the servers.

Comment: do you see CPU usage or memory usage spikes (graphs) ?

Comment: its showing 0.75% CPU usage and 419MB available RAM

Comment: check you pm2 logs you might be able to find the reason why process got killed.
`$ pm2 logs` https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Comment: There is nothing suspicious in  log file, it contains only my logging data except this error:
error connecting: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.